# jQuery equivalent to onclick in Ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp, jquery

I have 2 JSPs. And I am making an ajax call in 1st jsp and getting data(Ajax body) from 2nd jsp. I don't have a clue how to call jQuery when argument to function is present.

1. This is working fine.

   2nd JSP: `<html:link href="check()">status</html:link>`

   1st JSP: function check(){****}

   jQuery Equivalent is status
                        jQuery('#check').click(function(){****});
2. If argument is present,

   2nd JSP: `<h:link href="check('argument')">status</h:link>`

   1st JSP: function check('argument'){****};  //working fine

   I need equivalent jQuery script when argument is present.

**Concerns**: I Cannot put script in 2nd JSP since it will not be available in 1st JSP when Ajax call is made. I want argument to be available in 1st JSP

Answer (score 1):

I would use the data attribute to collect any parameters needed in the click handler

HTML:

```
<a href="" data-argument="something" id="check"></a>
```

JS:

```
$('#check').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // do whatever you need with this value now
    var val = $(this).data('argument');
    check(val);
});
```